# How exactly the dynamics of electrons flow works in a circuit with a single capacitor?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, capacitance, conductors, batteries

Does the difference in potential moves electrons from one plate to the battery higher potential side and simultaneosly moves electrons from the battery lower potential side to the other plate? And how exactly this works? Does battery absorb this electrons coming from one plate and generate new electrons for going to the other plate? Layman's Terms please, without getting into the complexity of how a battery works.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

when a surge of electrons moves through the wire to one plate of the capacitor, the electrons on the other plate "see" those electrons across the gap between the plates and are repelled by them- so there is a *temporary* surge of electrons "fleeing" out of the second plate.

As soon as the first plate has become fully occupied with extra electrons, the departure of electrons from the second plate comes to a halt- and note that there is NO FURTHER FLOW OF CURRENT into or out of the capacitor. This means that your picture is incorrect as drawn.

In this way, capacitors only allow brief surges of current to flow through them. Continuous DC current cannot flow through a capacitor.